# Irreducible representations and Abelian subgroups

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

There is a theorem in representation theory which is surprising to me: the dimension of irreducible (complex) representation of finite group is not greater that $(G:H)$ - an index of Abelian subgroup $H\subset G$. Can anyone provide a reference or a proof of this statement?

Comment: This is proved in Serre's little book on group representations or in Huppert's book on group characters.

Comment: I've found it, thank you!

Comment: Please add the complete references as an answer, so that this does not remain unanswered.

Comment: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Degree_of_irreducible_representation_is_bounded_by_index_of_abelian_subgroup

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $V$ is any irreducible representation of $G$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $V$ appears in the induced representation $\mathrm{Ind}(\mathrm{Res}(V))$, and this in fact implies that every irreducible representation of $G$ appears (as a summand of) $\mathrm{Ind}(W)$ for some irreducible representation of $H$.

If $H$ is abelian, every irreducible representation is one dimensional, and $\mathrm{Ind}(W)$ has dimension $[G:H]$, so the claim follows.

Comment: (N.B.: I am working in the nice setting, i.e. zero characteristic and algebraically closed field.)